# karate switchpage still not working even after the 1.1.0 fix

Tags: ui-automation, karate

switchpage is still not working even after 1.1.0 fix . I also validated the same with the older versions 1.1.0.RC5,RC4,RC3,RC2 and latest version 1.2.0.RC1 , none of them seems working !
Below is the sample script , even after the switchpage statement it returns the url of the original tab and none of the element being identified from the new tab !

Script

```
 Given driver 'https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open'
Then maximize()
When switchFrame('#iframeResult')
* print 'driver.url before switch----------------', driver.url
And highlight("{}Try it")
And click("{}Try it")
* delay(2000)
And switchPage('https://www.w3schools.com/')
* delay(2000)
* print 'driver.url after switch----------------', driver.url
* highlight("//a[@href='https://www.w3schools.com ']")
* delay(5000)
```

Console Log:

15:26:36.385 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] driver.url before switch---------------- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open
15:26:43.818 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] driver.url after switch---------------- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open

Comment: linked answer has some tips and workarounds. we also can't wait to get your code contribution to fix this ! thanks :)